# Directing non extension files to .php

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have a file with .php extention `www.example.com/thefile.php?name=123` that I want to direct the user to if the user visits any of the following aliases:

```
www.example.com/alias?name=123
www.example.com/unreal?name=123
www.example.com/fake?name=123
```

Is there a way I can get this done without using a framework that already uses this structure? I'm using pure php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, if you have mod_rewrite activated on your Apache Server, you can add a `.htaccess` file at the root of your website and have something like this into it (not 100% sure since I don't have Apache here at home) :

```
RewriteRule ^(alias|unreal|fake)$ thefile.php [QSA]
```

You can consult Apache [mod_rewrite doc here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use mod_rewrite and .htaccess files to achieve this (if you are running Apache that is).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache, you can use mod_rewrite to do this.

A nice article about it: [Using htaccess Files for Pretty URLS](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/)